# Where did Samuel Johnson say Macbeth is wholly reviled?

Tags: william-shakespeare, macbeth, samuel-johnson

The [Wikipedia article about Shakespeare's *Macbeth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Macbeth&oldid=972914626#As_a_tragedy_of_character) contains a section on reading the play as a tragedy of character. This section contains the following unsourced statement:

> Johnson asserted that Macbeth, though esteemed for his military bravery, is wholly reviled.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>

I tried to find a source for this in [*Johnson on Shakespeare*, edited by Walter Raleigh, 1908](https://archive.org/details/johnsononshakesp00johnuoft) (on Archive.org) and on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=samuel+johnson+macbeth+reviled) but without success. Where did Johnson make this statement? (Did he actually use the word "reviled"?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Samuel Johnson's [*General Observations on the plays of Shakespeare*](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139056472.006) (I couldn't find a full text of this publication online, but it's quoted in several places including the paper [Arthur Sherbo, "Dr. Johnson on Macbeth: 1745 and 1765", *The Review of English Studies* 2(5) (1951), pp. 40-47](https://www.jstor.org/stable/511908?seq=8#metadata_info_tab_contents), which claims this quote to be at pp. 161-162):

> The passions are directed to their true end. Lady Macbeth is merely detested; and though the courage of Macbeth preserves some esteem, yet every reader rejoices at his fall.

This may be the sentence which has been re-told for the Wikipedia page. The word "revile" is not there, but the word "esteem" is, specifically in reference to Macbeth's "courage" (presumably meaning on the field of battle), and *wholly reviled* is not an unreasonable conclusion to draw if "every reader rejoices" at the defeat and death of Macbeth.

Comment: http://www.yalejohnson.com/frontend/sda_viewer?n=108512